# Find the limit: $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\lfloor\sqrt{2n-1-\cos(n)}\rfloor}{2\sqrt{n}+3}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Please keep in mind that I am new to limits as we have just touched limits in the semester.

I have the limit

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\left\lfloor\sqrt{2n-1-\cos(n)}\right\rfloor}{2\sqrt{n}+3}$$

How do I calculate it?
<strike>I thought of expanding the square root in the numerator as:

$\lfloor\sqrt{2}*\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{1}-\sqrt{cos(n)}\rfloor$

And then go from that.</strike> 

Because from that we can actually see that the denominator will grow faster than the numerator so I suspect that the limit will be 0?

//EDIT Based on @student91 answer

I have:

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{2n-2}-1}{2\sqrt{n}+3} \le \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\lfloor\sqrt{2n-1-cos(n)}\rfloor}{2\sqrt{n}+3} \le \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{2n}}{2\sqrt{n}+3} $

**Last limit** $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{2n}}{2\sqrt{n}+3}$:

= $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{n}}{2\sqrt{n}+3}$
= $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}+3}$
= $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{1+\frac{3}{\sqrt{n}}}$ = $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\lim_{n\to\infty}1+\frac{3}{\sqrt{n}}}$
= $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{1} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$

Where

$\lim_{n\to\infty}1+\frac{3}{n}$ = 1

But I am not exactly sure how to solve the left most limit:
$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{2n-2}-1}{2\sqrt{n}+3}$

Comment: $\sqrt{2n-1}$ is not the same as $\sqrt{2n}-\sqrt{1}$. Try it for $n=1,2,3,\dots$, you'll get different results.

Comment: Oh, then my only idea is wrong.

Comment: My first idea would be to use the fact that $\cos(n)$ is always at least $-1$ and at most $1$. Then use the Squeeze Theorem. And if that doesn't work, my second idea would be to apply L'Hospital's rule.

Comment: As $n\to\infty$, $\sqrt{2n-1-\cos(n)} \sim \sqrt{2n}$, that should work

Comment: What is the context for this question? Do you need to give an explicit proof using a definition similar to $\exists l,\ \forall\varepsilon>0,\ \exists N,\ \forall n>N \left|\frac{\lfloor\sqrt{2n-1-\cos n}\rfloor}{2\sqrt n-3}-l\right|<\varepsilon$ or do you have a less formal approach to limits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint 1: We have that $\frac{\sqrt{2n-1-cos(n)}-1}{2\sqrt{n}+3}<\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\lfloor\sqrt{2n-1-cos(n)}\rfloor}{2\sqrt{n}+3}\le \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{2n-1-cos(n)}}{2\sqrt{n}+3}$ for all $n$. Can you calculate the limits $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{2n-1-cos(n)}-1}{2\sqrt{n}+3}$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{2n-1-cos(n)}}{2\sqrt{n}+3}$? Do you know the [squeezing theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Squeeze_Theorem/Sequences/Real_Numbers)?

Hint 2:
You can divide both the numerator and denominator by $\sqrt n$, which gives $\sqrt{2-\frac 1n-\frac{\cos n}n}$ for the numerator and $2+\frac3{\sqrt n}$ for the denominator. Can you calculate these limits? Do you know the [combination rules](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Combination_Theorem_for_Sequences) for limits?

Hint 3: The square root $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is [continuous](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Limit_of_Image_of_Sequence/Real_Number_Line).

Comment: I have edited my question based on your answer. Please check it now. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I just realised that I used the wrong limit definition for my solution. Let me reevaluate.

Comment: Okay @student91 I updated my question now, hopefully something is correct.

Comment: After the edit, you say $\frac\infty\infty=1$, which is not correct. $\frac\infty\infty$ is an [indeterminate form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form), and you do not know if it is $1$ or something else. You should look at Hint 2 first.

Comment: After your second edit, it is correct

Comment: Hmm, I will try to divide it by $\sqrt{n}$, but how did you come up with that? Does the limit itself somehow tell that you should divide it by that?

Comment: When you look at $2\sqrt n + 3$, you see that it is of the form $2n^{\frac12}+3$. You know that $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{-a}=0$ for $a>0$, so multiplying this with $n^{-\frac12}$ will give something with a finite limit (meaning not $0$ and not $\infty$). Then the numerator should also have a limit when multiplied with $n^{-\frac12}$, or the original limit does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

First note the following two properties: 
$x-1 \leq \lfloor x \rfloor \leq x$ , $-1 \leq \cos(x) \leq 1$ 
Now notice that: 
$\frac{\sqrt{2n-2}-1}{2\sqrt{n}+3} \leq \frac{\lfloor\sqrt{2n-1-\cos(n)}\rfloor}{2\sqrt{n}+3} \leq \frac{\sqrt{2n}}{2\sqrt{n}+3}$ 
Can you finish the exercise by using the squeeze theorem ?